# Is this sentence by Angela Merkel grammatically correct?

Tags: adjective, dative

The below paragraph appears in todays's article “[Trump vs. Merkel beim Nato-Gipfel. Duell auf offener Bühne.](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/trump-vs-merkel-beim-nato-gipfel-duell-auf-offener-buehne-a-1217946.html)” from *Der Spiegel*:

> Soweit, so normal. Dann aber fügt sie [Angela Merkel] hinzu, "dass wir unsere eigenständige Politik machen können" und "eigenständige Entscheidungen fällen können". *Und weiter: "Ich möchte **aus gegebenen Anlass** hinzufügen, dass ich erlebt habe, auch selber, dass ein Teil Deutschlands von der Sowjetunion kontrolliert wurde."*

My question refers to the second sentence in the above-quoted paragraph: Why *aus gegebene**n** Anlass* and not *aus gegebene**m** Anlass* (that is, *n* instead of *m* at the end of *gegebene*)? According to [dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=aus%20gegebenem%20Anlass), the phrase should read: *aus gegebene**m** Anlass*. As far as I know, an adjective following *aus* and preceding a masculine noun (der Anlass) should have an ending of *-em*, not *-en*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right, it should be *aus gegebenem Anlass*.

However: If you listen to the actual [interview in the video](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/angela-merkel-kanzlerin-kontert-kritik-von-donald-trump-bei-nato-gipfel-a-1217862.html) (at around 0:40), which was linked in the article you mentioned, you can hear, that Merkel said *aus gegebenem Anlass*.

This case just shows, that also journalists are not faultless.

Comment: How dare you! I was a journalist! I know better!

Comment: That explains a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Da ist ja alles falsch!

> Dann aber fügt sie [Angela Merkel] hinzu, "dass wir unsere
>   eigenständige Politik machen können" und "eigenständige Entscheidungen
>   fällen können".

Das ist als direkte Rede gesetzt, ist aber indirekte Rede. Entweder als direkte Rede:

"Wir können unsere eigenständige Politik machen und eigenständige Entscheidungen fällen."

Besser wäre natürlich, jetzt sind wir bei Fehlern Merkels: "Wir können eigenständig Politik machen und Entscheidungen fällen".

oder als indirekte:

> Dann aber fügt sie [Angela Merkel] hinzu, dass wir unsere
>   eigenständige Politik machen können und eigenständige Entscheidungen
>   fällen können.

Das ist aber Presseunsitte, indirekte Rede als Zitat zu kennzeichnen, obwohl es keins ist.

> Und weiter: "Ich möchte aus gegebenem Anlass hinzufügen, dass ich erlebt habe, auch selber, dass ein Teil Deutschlands von der Sowjetunion kontrolliert wurde."

Auf jeden Fall muss es, wie richtig vermutet und Frageanlass, 'gegebenem Anlass' heißen.

Die Fehler Merkels:

Was man erlebt hat, hat man immer selbst erlebt - sonst hat man es nicht erlebt. Was hat sie erlebt? Dass ein Teil Deutschlands von der SU kontrolliert wird, natürlich, nicht dass er kontrolliert wurde - das hieße ja zu erleben, was bereits abgeschlossen ist.

"Selbst erlebt" könnte man als Bekräftigung durchgehen lassen, aber nicht "auch selber":

> "Ich möchte aus gegebenem Anlass hinzufügen, dass ich selbst erlebt habe, dass ein Teil Deutschlands von der Sowjetunion kontrolliert wird."

Comment: Abgesehen von der Tatsache, dass gesprochene Sprache und ausgefeilte Schriftsprache zwei verschiedene Paar Schuhe sind: a) Den Einschub "auch selber" verstehe ich als Hinweis darauf, dass Merkel damals in der DDR gelebt hat. Sie möchte klarstellen, dass sie nicht lediglich von außen Zeugin war. b) Superstreng grammatikalisch mögen die Zeitstufen so zu konstruieren sein - das Ergebnis klingt dennoch auf den ersten Blick nach Verschwörungstheorie, als ob sie der Meinung wäre, die Sowjetunion kontolliere immer noch einen Teil Deutschlands. Eindeutigkeit sollte im Zweifel Vorrang haben.

Comment: Die Zitate gehen so völlig in Ordnung. Sie hat die zitierten Satzteile so, als Nebensätze, gesagt: "Ich bin sehr froh, dass wir heute in Freiheit vereint sind - als die Bundesrepublik Deutschland - und dass wir deshalb auch sagen können, dass wir unsere eigenständige Politik machen können und eigenständige Entscheidungen fällen können."

Comment: Am meisten interessiert mich bei der Antwort, ob der Schreibfehler im letzten Block Absicht war ;)

Comment: @RichardMetzler: Wie die Satzfragmente zitiert werden legt aber die Vermutung nahe, dass hier indirekte Rede benutzt wird. Merkel hat eben nicht gesagt, dass wir unsere eigene Politik machen können, sondern nur, dass wir das sagen können. Die Fehlinformation ist also sprachlich noch schlimmer als gedacht. Dass sie damit nicht nur sagen wollte, dass wir das sagen können, sondern dass es auch wirklich so ist ändert nichts daran, dass die Zitierweise in die Irre führt.

Comment: @tallistroan: Nein, ein Copy-Paste-Fehler, der mir nicht aufgefallen ist. Ich musste jetzt auch 3x lesen, um die Autokorrektur meines Hirns auszuschalten und den Fehler zu finden. :)

Comment: @Mac: Vielleicht hast Du recht. Mir scheint, man sagt normalerweise etwas wie: "Ich habe selbst erlebt, wie das Wasser über die Ufer tritt". Oder: "Ich habe erlebt, dass eine Mannschaft in einem Spiel 4x den Pfosten trifft".